# List is empty but this is supposed to return something

Tags: python, selenium

```
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import os
import time
def main():
    driver = configuration()
    rechercher(driver,'python')

def configuration():
    """
    Permet de faire la configuration nécessaire pour faire le scraping
    :return: driver
    """

    path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get("https://ca.indeed.com/")
    return driver
def rechercher(driver,motcle):
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]')
    search.send_keys(motcle)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="resultsCol"]')))
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')
    for x in content:
        print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am confused. Everything looks fine to me but the list is empty. Probably this is obvious but I cannot find the issue. I know there are plenty of result and I only found the class name in common with all the elements I want to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives me results. Note the use of `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead of `find_elements_by_class_name`. "If there are spaces in the class name, `find_elements_by_class_name` does not work." - probably because then you'll have multiple class names.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get("https://ca.indeed.com/")

    search = driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-what")
    search.send_keys('python')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"resultsCol")))
    content = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.jobsearch-SerpJobCard.unifiedRow.row.result.clickcard')
    for x in content:
        print(x.text)
```